# ORA-00936 missing expression

Tags: c#, oracle

i need to update my table column votecount when a user voted but im having this error and i dont know what to do with it.

```
 private void Vote(string VoteId)
    {

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATE ADMIN.CANDIDATES SET VOTE_COUNT=(VOTE_COUNT+1) WHERE PRSDENT=@Prsdent");
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prsdent", VoteId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to change your parameter `@Prsdent` to `:Prsdent`

See: [OracleCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When using named parameters in an SQL statement called by an
>   OracleCommand of CommandType.Text, you **must precede the parameter
>   name with a colon (:).**

Also consider enclosing your command and connection object in [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) as that will ensure proper disposal of resources.